# Programa que reciba 3 números enteros y genere como salida las combinaciones que se pueden hacer con esos tres números

Tags: c#, ordenamiento, ordenar, permutaciones

Ejemplo:
Entradas = 1, 2, 3
Salida = “1,2,3” - “1,3,2” - “2,1,3” - “2,3,1” - “3,1,2” - “3,2,1”

Estoy atorado con este problema, ya busqué métodos de ordenamiento, de permutación y combinación sin embargo no logro hacer esa combinación.

Lo estoy haciendo mediante un array, sin embargo no logro obtener esos resultados:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int[] numeros = {0, 0, 0};
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el primer número: ");
        numeros[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el segundo número: ");
        numeros[1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el tercer número: ");
        numeros[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for(int i = 0; i<= 1; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 1; j <= 2; j++)
            {
                for(int k = 2; k <= 3; k++)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{" + numeros[i] + "," + numeros[j] + "," + numeros[k] + "}" + 
                              " - " + "{" + numeros[i] + "," + numeros[k] + "," + numeros[j] + "}" + 
                              " - " + "{" + numeros[j] + "," + numeros[i] + "," + numeros[k] + "}" +
                              " - " + "{" + numeros[j] + "," + numeros[k] + "," + numeros[i] + "}" +
                              " - " + "{" + numeros[k] + "," + numeros[i] + "," + numeros[j] + "}" +
                              " - " + "{" + numeros[k] + "," + numeros[j] + "," + numeros[i] + "}");                                            
                }
            }
        }    
    }    
}
```

Salida:

Ingresa el primer número:
1
Ingresa el segundo número:
2
Ingresa el tercer número:
3
{1,2,3} - {1,3,2} - {2,1,3} - {2,3,1} - {3,1,2} - {3,2,1}

obviamente está mal...

Comment: Por qué dices que *obviamente está mal*? La salida que tienes al final de la pregunta, es **EXACTAMENTE** igual al ejemplo que pones al comienzo. Por favor, aclara la pregunta incluyendo cuál es la salida actual y la salida esperada.

Comment: Hola diego podrias decir si las respuestas dadas te fueron utiles y marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado, gracias

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo que quieres hacer se llama generar **permutaciones sin repetición**, aquí te pongo un código que genera permutaciones para la **secuencia 1, 2, 3**.

Lo que se hace aquí es **3 ciclos for anidados** que van desde el **1** hasta el **3**, y dentro del **ciclo for** más interno se pregunta si todos los índices de los **ciclos for (i, j, k)** son diferentes entre sí, de ser diferentes, se genera entonces la **permutación sin repetición:**.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
   for (int j = 1; j <= 3; j++)
   {
      for (int k = 1; k <= 3; k++)
      {
         if(i != j && i != k && j != k)
         {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}, {1}, {2}", i, j, k));
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Para saber la cantidad de permutaciones que se pueden generar en tu secuencia debes calcular el factorial del total de elementos que tiene tu secuencia, es decir en tu ejemplo tu secuencia es (**1**, **2**, **3**), esta secuencia tiene un total de **3** elementos, por lo que el factorial de este total es **6**.

```
3! = 3 * 2 * 1 = 6 permutaciones.
```

Si tu secuencia fuera por ejemplo (**1**, **2**, **3**, **4**), entonces:

```
4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 = 24 permutaciones
```

## Actualización:

También puedes usar **recursividad** para generar permutaciones:

```
public static void Permutaciones(int[] entrada, int[] permutacion, int indice, bool[] visitada)
{
    if (indice == permutacion.Length)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", permutacion[0], permutacion[1], permutacion[2]);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int k = 0; k < permutacion.Length; k++)
        {
            if (!visitada[k])
            {
                visitada[k] = true;
                permutacion[indice] = entrada[k];
                Permutaciones(entrada, permutacion, indice + 1, visitada);
                visitada[k] = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Esta función consta de 4 parámetros:

**entrada**: Es un arreglo de enteros el cual va a contener la secuencia de números que van a ser permutados.

**permutacion**: Es un arreglo de enteros que almacenará cada permutación generada.

**indice**: variable entera que servirá de índice para ir almacenando cada elemento permutado en el **arreglo permutacion**.

**visitada**: arreglo booleano que se utiliza para garantizar que la permutación no contenga elementos repetidos.

Al ser un **algoritmo recursivo** consta de un **caso base** y un **caso recursivo**. El **caso base** se cumple cuando el **arreglo permutacion** está lleno, y entonces se imprime la permutación obtenida. Mientras no se cumpla el **caso base** la función se irá invocando recursivamente generando a partir de los datos de entrada las permutaciones correspondientes.

Para llamar a esta función se haría lo siguiente:

```
Permutaciones(new int[3] {1, 2, 3}, new int[3], 0, new bool[3]);
```

Comment: Vaya !!!, que buena respuesta. Me gusta

Comment: @Vanessa, gracias linda!!

Answer (score 2):

Si respetamos tu código simplemente nos olvidamos de los bucles

```
static void Main()
    {
        int[] numeros = { 0, 0, 0 };
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el primer número: ");
        numeros[0] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el segundo número: ");
        numeros[1] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("Ingresa el tercer número: ");
        numeros[2] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        //creamos tres variables enteras para cada una de las filas del array
        int o = 0, p = 1, q = 2;
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("Impresión distintas posiciones de valores");
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
        //usamos tu código para imprimir los valores sustituyendo las variables de los bucles por las variables creadas en el paso anterior
        Console.WriteLine("{" + numeros[o] + ", " + numeros[p] + ", " + numeros[q] + "}" +
                " - " + "{" + numeros[q] + ", " + numeros[p] + ", " + numeros[o] + "}" +
                " - " + "{" + numeros[p] + ", " + numeros[o] + ", " + numeros[q] + "}" +
                " - " + "{" + numeros[p] + ", " + numeros[q] + ", " + numeros[o] + "}" +
                " - " + "{" + numeros[q] + ", " + numeros[o] + ", " + numeros[p] + "}" +
                " - " + "{" + numeros[q] + ", " + numeros[p] + ", " + numeros[o] + "}");
    }
```